# Text in rounded corners and hover not working

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="round">
        <img src="favicon.png" align="center" /><br />Power and Electricity
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="round">
        <img src="favicon.png" align="center" /><br />Power and Electricity
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="round">
        <img src="favicon.png" align="center" /><br />Power and Electricity
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="round">
        <img src="favicon.png" align="center" /><br />Power and Electricity
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.round{
    -moz-border-radius:50%;  /* for Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius:50%; /* for Webkit-Browsers */
    border-radius:50%; /* regular */
    opacity:1; /* Transparent Background 50% */
    background:#eee;
    padding:40px;
    height:70px;
    width:70px;
    text-align: center;
    alignment-adjust: middle;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
}
.round:hover{
    -moz-border-radius:50%;  /* for Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius:50%; /* for Webkit-Browsers */
    border-radius:50%; /* regular */
    opacity:1; /* Transparent Background 50% */
    background:#000;
    padding:40px;
    height:70px;
    width:70px;
    text-align: center;
    alignment-adjust: middle;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
}
```

and goes my questions:

1. Why is the text decoration not working?
2. The text changes color on hover but not the underline! Why?
3. All the div appears in vertical one after another. How do i place it horizontally across the screen and auto have it come to second row at the end of the screen?
4. Is this the best practice? Which browsers will this not work on? I tried on all the latest version of safari, chrome and firefox. Not sure if it will work on IE8

Comment: You don't need `-moz-border-radius` (unless you want to support Firefox 3 users). And no, you're right, `border-radius` doesn't work in IE8. (there are [polyfills you can use to fix that](http://css3pie.com/) though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a `div` within the `a`, just put the `round` class on the `a`.:

```
<a class="round" href="#"><img src="favicon.png" align="center" /><br />Power and Electricity</a>
```

Then add `.round{display:inline-block;}` and you're all set.

http://jsfiddle.net/FRz3H/

Comment: border-radius doesn't work on IE8, but I usually just let IE8 users see squared-off stuff and don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

a:hover is overriding div:hover, you should create a seperate class for a and define `text-decoration:none` for that. Aligning problem is probably occuring from the same issue, the outer tag is a so you should define css for it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the color property on the anchor element. And you don't have to redeclare identical CSS properties for :hover or any other so called pseudo-classes. A good rule of thumb is to do the most with as less as possible HTML elements and remain semantics. Doesn't work for IE8.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="round">Power and Electricity</a> 
<a href="#" class="round">Power and Electricity</a> 
<a href="#" class="round">Power and Electricity</a> 
<a href="#" class="round">Power and Electricity</a>
```

CSS

```
.round {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius:50%;  /* for Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius:50%; /* for Webkit-Browsers */
  border-radius:50%; /* regular */
  opacity:1; /* Transparent Background 50% */
  background:#eee;
  padding:40px;
  height:70px;
  width:70px;
  text-align: center;
}
.round:hover{
  color: #fff;
  background:#000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbWPX/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the class to the anchor tag instead of the div, or create a  new class and assign it to the anchor tag where the text-decoration: none will be there

Example:

`<a href="#" class="roundHyperlink"><div class="round"><img src="favicon.png" align="center"><br />Power and Electricity</div></a>`

```
.roundHyperlink
{
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: thank you so much. i spent over 2 hours on this already!!! should have posted here a long time ago :) :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, then please mark it as answer and give it a upvote please.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the div and display the anchor as a block, than your question 1&2 is answered:
To answer 3, add a float left.

HTML:

```
<a class="round" href="#">
    <img src="favicon.png" align="center" /><br />Power and Electricity
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.round{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    .....
}
```

Also check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/v2ycW/).